# how can i sort this table by column?

Tags: java, sorting

https://www.mediafire.com/#myfiles

got this program, and i can't sort the table by column , i use bubble sort but the table does not update the the list after sorting , just using the table as temporary storage no database .

thanks for those who can help me.

```
 else if(e.getActionCommand().equals( "SORT" )) {
     String []list = new String[data.length];
     for (int row = 0; row < data.length; row++) {
        list[row] = (String) data[row][0];
     }
     for(int row=0;row<noOfStudents;row++){
         for(int column=0;column<noOfStudents;column++){
             if(list[column].compareTo(list[column+1])<0){
                 String a = list[column];
                 list[column]=list[column+1];
                 list[column+1]= a;
             }
         }
     }
     for(int row=0;row<noOfStudents;row++) {
            data[row][0]=list[row];
     }
     for(int row=0;row<noOfStudents;row++) {
            table.setValueAt(list[row], row, 0);
     }
 }
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see a textual representation of an unsorted array of values, and then what it looks like after sorting. I don't understand what you are trying to achieve by looking at the code you have posted.

Comment: Your mediafire link is taking me to a "log in or signup page". Links are discouraged on stackoverflow anyway...

Answer (score 0):

I have not fully understood the code but why you don't use:

```
 Arrays.sort(list);
```

Comment: Isn't this more appropriate as a comment?